# Creating Nested JSON from Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe and have to convert it into nested JSON.

```
countryname  name  text   score
UK           ABC   Hello  5
```

Right now, I have some code that generates JSON, grouping `countryname` and `name`.
However, I want to firstly group by `countryname` and then group by `name`. Below is the code and output:

```
cols = test.columns.difference(['countryname','name'])
j = (test.groupby(['countryname','name'])[cols]
   .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r'))
   .reset_index(name='results')
   .to_json(orient='records'))
test_json = json.dumps(json.loads(j), indent=4)

Output:
[
 {
  "countryname":"UK"
  "name":"ABC"
   "results":[
     {
      "text":"Hello"
      "score":"5"
     }
    ]
    }
   ]
```

However, I am expecting an output like this:

```
[
 {
  "countryname":"UK"
  {
  "name":"ABC"
   "results":[
     {
      "text":"Hello"
      "score":"5"
     }
    ]
    }
   }
   ]
```

Can anyone please help in fixing this?

Comment: i want to first groupby countryname, then groupby name with the values inside them

Answer (score -1):

This would be the valid JSON. Note the comma `,` usage, is required as you may check [`here`](https://jsonlint.com/).

```
[
 {
  "countryname":"UK",
  "name":"ABC",
   "results":[
     {
      "text":"Hello",
      "score":"5"
     }
    ]
    }
   ]
```

The other output you try to achieve is also not according to the standard:

```
[{
    "countryname": "UK",
    "you need a name in here": {
        "name": "ABC",
        "results": [{
            "text": "Hello",
            "score": "5"
        }]
    }
}]
```

I improved that so you can figure out what name to use.
For custom JSON output you will need to use custom function to reformat your object first.

```
l=df.to_dict('records')[0] #to get the list
print(l, type(l)) #{'countryname': 'UK', 'name': 'ABC', 'text': 'Hello', 'score': 5} <class 'dict'>

e = l['countryname']
print(e) # UK

o=[{
    "countryname": l['countryname'],
    "you need a name in here": {
        "name": l['name'],
        "results": [{
            "text": l['text'],
            "score": l['score']
        }]
    }
}]

print(o) #[{'countryname': 'UK', 'you need a name in here': {'name': 'ABC', 'results': [{'text': 'Hello', 'score': 5}]}}]
```